# Wilf's conjecture: complementary Bell numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, permutations, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

The *complementary* Bell numbers or [Uppuluri–Carpenter numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementaryBellNumber.html), denoted $\tilde{B}_n$, can be delivered by
$$G(x):=\sum_{n\geq0}\tilde{B}_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{1-e^x}.$$
**Definition.** Fix an integer $m\geq0$. We say $F(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ has the index-m property whenever $a_n=0$ iff $n=m$ is satisfied.

In this language, Herb Wilf's conjecture can be stated as: *$G(x)$ has the index-2 property*.

By now, there are a few papers turning this into a theorem, including this one:

> Tewodros Amdeberhan, Valerio De Angelis and Victor H. Moll, *Complementary Bell Numbers: Arithmetical Properties and Wilf’s Conjecture* (2013) In: Kotsireas I., Zima E. (eds) Advances in Combinatorics. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, doi:[10.1007/978-3-642-30979-3_2](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-30979-3_2) ([pdf](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/%7Evhm/papers_html/final-bell.pdf))

The other day, I started pondering on a *truncated* version of the generating function, namely, **for** $\pmb{r\geq2}$, define
$$G_r(x)=e^{-(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots+\frac{x^r}{r!})}=\sum_{n\geq0}\tilde{B}_{n,r}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Of course, $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}G_r(x)=G(x)$.
After some experimentation, I'm enough convinced to ask:

> **Question 1.** Fix $r\geq2$. Is it true that $G_r(x)$ has the index-2 property?
>
> **Question 2.** Does Wilf's conjecture imply the claim in Question 1? Or, vise-versa?

An aside: the functions $G_r(x)$ are equally interesting as related to partition theory, Hermite polynomials, permutations, Young tableaux, etc.

**UPDATE.**

(1) From $G_{r+1}(x)=G_r(x)\cdot e^{-\frac{x^{r+1}}{(r+1)!}}$, it follows that $\tilde{B}_{n,r+1}=\tilde{B}_{n,r}$ for all $n\leq r$. By the same reasoning, $\tilde{B}_n=\tilde{B}_{n,r}$ for all $n\leq r$. It is now clear that $\tilde{B}_{n,r}=0$ iff $n=2$, for all $r$, implies $\tilde{B}_n=0$ iff $n=2$. This related to a part of Question 2.

(2) It is also possible to prove if $G(x)$ has index-2 property then so does $G_r(x)$, for large enough $r$. Again, this is related to a part of Question 2.

(3) The case $G_2(x)$ has index-2 property is known:

> Solution by R. Israel to a problem proposed by F. Schmidt and R. Simion, *Even minus odd involutions in the symmetric group*,  SIAM Rev. 34 (2), pages 315-317 (1992) doi:[10.1137/1034062](https://doi.org/10.1137/1034062).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261409/generalizing-wilfs-conjecture-uppuluri-carpenter-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Israel's explicit formula implies that the (positive) binomial transform of $\tilde B_{n,2}$ is an aerated sequence of double factorials. The binomial transform for general $r$ experimentally has small prime factors, suggesting a similar explicit formula.